# Git alias on Windows: How to escape double quotes

Tags: windows, git

I am on a Windows 10 Pro Machine and I am using [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) with Git version `2.15.0.windows.1`.

I want to set up an alias for the git log command with some pretty options. The command is:

```
log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate
```

When I try to set the alias up by running this command:

```
git config --global alias.ls "log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate"
```

It does not work, the alias is not registered. I suspect it is because I have double quotes within the command too.

I also tried wrapping it with single quotes `'`, but that does not work either.

How can I escape those double quotes within the command so that the alias does register?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single quotes for the pretty=format string.

```
git config --global alias.ls "log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]' --decorate"
```